# Gathering Values between XML tags in Python

Tags: python, xml, export-to-csv

Here's my code Dunno why I'm getting an empty dataframe. I have tried using BeautifulSoup too but did not work well as well. I just need the value between the tags.

```py
root = ET.parse("DLTINS_20210117_01of01.xml").getroot()
for i in root.findall("FinInstrmRptgRefDataDltaRpt"):
    for j in i.findall("FinInstrmGnlAttrbts"):
            Id = j.find("Id").text
            FullNm = j.find("FullNm").text
            ClssfctnTp = j.find("ClssfctnTp").text
            CmmdtyDerivInd = j.find("CmmdtyDerivInd").text
            NtnlCcy = j.find("NtnlCcy").text
            Issr = i.find("Issr").text
            rows.append({
                "Id":Id,
                "FullNm":FullNm,
                "ClssfctnTp":ClssfctnTp,
                "CmmdtyDerivInd":CmmdtyDerivInd,
                "NtnlCcy":NtnlCcy,
                "Issr":Issr
                })
df = pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=cols)
```

[Here's the XML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fVAp.png)

Comment: Please provide the XML as text, not as an image.

Comment: Please provide all `import` lines as `ET` can be from a number of XML package.

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)